# Trigger On Task Object

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to write trigger on task object

On Contact workflow will fire based on fields update:
[image]

This workflow will create task with related to this Contact:

Now there is survey Object and and there are few survey records with this contact:

[image]

Now i need to update the task field called Related to With the condition of Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = TRUE of Survey record with related to same contact

[image]

[image]

This is what created trigger but when creating Task i am getting nothing. Can you please any one help me find solution:

```
public class TaskTriggerActions {

public static void RecentSurvey(List<Task> lTask) {
    Set<Id> completedIds = new Set<Id>();
    Task[] scoredTasks = new Task[0];
    for(Task record: lTask) {
        if(record.WhoId != null && record.Subject != null &&
        record.Subject.contains('Contact scored one or more questions')) {
            //Add the task id to the array and contactid to the set 
            scoredTasks.add(record);
            completedIds.add(record.WhoId);
        }
        system.debug('List of Task Ids: '+scoredTasks);
        system.debug('List of WhoIds: '+completedIds);
    }
    if(scoredTasks.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    //Get all the surveys related to the contact in the task
    Map<Id, Id> contactToSurveys = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Survey__c record: [SELECT Contact__c FROM Survey__c WHERE Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = TRUE AND Contact__c IN :completedIds]) {
        contactToSurveys.put(record.Contact__c, record.Id);
        system.debug('List of Surveys: '+contactToSurveys);
    }
    //Trasfer the survey id from the map to the instance of original task
    for(Task record: scoredTasks) {
        record.WhatId = contactToSurveys.get(record.Id);
        system.debug('Task what id: '+record.whatid);
    }
  }}
```

Here is my debug:

[image]

Please find Handler and Trigger:

```
 public class TaskTriggerHandler {
 //variable declaration
  private boolean m_isExecuting = false;
  private integer BatchSize = 0;

//constructor
  public TaskTriggerHandler(boolean isExecuting, integer size){
    m_isExecuting = isExecuting;
    BatchSize = size;
}

 public void OnBeforeInsert(List<Task> triggerNew){   

 TaskTriggerActions.RecentSurvey(triggerNew);
}//end of before Insert

public void OnAfterInsert(List<Task> triggerNew){    
}//end of after Insert

public void OnBeforeUpdate(List<Task> triggerNew){    
}//end of before Update

public void OnAfterUpdate(List<Task> triggerNew){    
}//end of after Update

}
```

Trigger

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert,after insert,before update,after update) {

Trigger_Controls__c CS = Trigger_Controls__c.getOrgDefaults();
if(CS.Task_Trigger__c){// trigger toggle
    TaskTriggerHandler handler = new TaskTriggerHandler (Trigger.isExecuting, Trigger.size);
     //Runs on before insert only
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {    
        handler.OnBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
    }//e
    //Runs on after insert only
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {    
        handler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
    }//end of after insert condition

    //Runs on before update only 
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {    
        handler.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.new);
    }//end of before update condition

        //Runs on after update only 
   //  if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {  
   //              handler.OnAfterUpdate(trigger.new,trigger.old,trigger.newMap,trigger.oldMap);
   //}//end of afte update condition
 }// end of trigger toggle

   }
```

[image]

Comment: So what is the output of your debugs?

Comment: There is a debug and nothing happening. Finally i need to assign the survey record to that Related To (WhatId).

Comment: Can you share the task trigger? I can only see the class, maybe your trigger isn't calling the class...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I appreciate. Please find Trigger and handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is collect the Contact Ids as you are now and query the Contacts directly with the Surveys as a subquery.  This way it's easier to associate the Survey with the right Contact.

Here is some sample code.

```
// SOQL Query gets all Contacts and their child surveys (assuming Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = TRUE results in only one survey per contact)
Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Surveys__r WHERE Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = true) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :completedIDs]);

for(Task record : scoredTasks)
{
    // Get the contact
    Contact c = contactMap.get(record.WhoId);
    // Make sure a Contact record was found, and it has at least one survey record
    if(c != null && !c.Surveys__r.isEmpty())
    {
        // Get the survey record
        Survey__c survey = c.Surveys__r[0];

        // Assign Survey to Task record
        record.WhatId = survey.Id;
    }
}
```

My code assumes that the WHERE condition `WHERE Most_Recent_NPS_Survey__c = true` will return at max one survey.  If this is not the case then you may need to do some extra processing to ensure you get the right survey with score < 7

Comment: I am getting error at this line  "Survey__c survey = contactMap.Surveys__r[0];    
"      Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Map<Id,Contact> at line 33 column 28 
Should i use get or how overcome it ?

Comment: There was a typo in my code.  I updated my answer, basically change `Survey__c survey = contactMap.Surveys__r[0];` to `Survey__c survey = c.Surveys__r[0];`

Comment: Hi you code was good but nothing happening. The related To is not updated and Why I'm not getting Logs that is what weird for me.

Comment: @NeymarDaSilva Are you sure the code is actually being run?  Can you double check your Trigger_Controls__c custom setting to ensure that Task_Trigger__c is evaluating to TRUE

Comment: Yes that is default Checked. Please see the picture

Comment: @NeymarDaSilva The picture of your Debug logs only shows a Managed Package called GroupAlert running.  Can you increase the detail of your logs and then post a new set of debug logs?